# highligting when switching to another buffer

Tags: emacs

I have a problem when switching to another buffers, since I have a 27'' imac, and so many buffers in a window, when I switch to another window, I am always lost, I don't know which window I am now, is there any way to highlight the current window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the mode line, for example:

```
(set-face-attribute  'mode-line          nil  :foreground "black"  :background "ivory"  :box '(:line-width 1 :style released-button))
(set-face-attribute  'mode-line-inactive nil  :foreground "gray30" :background "black"  :box '(:line-width 1 :style released-button))
```

You can see the result on the following image. The active mode line is white (more exactly ivory). Inactive mode lines are black.

[image: customized mode-line]

Comment: Colors for active and inactive mode lines depend on your color schema.   Your color's choice may be different from mine.